# I am developing a chrome extension by which I want to automate the form filling process

Tags: javascript

I am getting some CSP errors which is not allowing to get access of that web page.

Here I am attaching my content.js file which is responsible for data injection into web page

```
// Listen for messages from the background script
const port = chrome.runtime.connect({ name: "formData" });

let DataStore;

port.postMessage({ action: "getFormData" });
port.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
  let formData = message.formData;
  DataStore = formData;
  console.log(DataStore);
})

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async function () {
  const Mybutton = document.getElementById('myButton');
  console.log("I am waiting for event click");
  await Mybutton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log("Clicked");

    if (DataStore) {
      console.log(DataStore);
      const ServentUploadForm = document.querySelector("#ContentPlaceHolder1_pnlvisible");
      console.log(ServentUploadForm);
      const ServentID = document.querySelector("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtSIdNo");
      const ServentFName = document.querySelector("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtSFirstName");
      const ServentLName = document.querySelector("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtSLastName");
      const ServentFFName = document.querySelector("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtSFirstFName");
      const ServentFLName = document.querySelector("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtSLastFName");
      console.log("Variable Created", ServentFFName,ServentFLName,ServentFName,ServentLName,ServentID);
      const firstRecord = DataStore[0];
      console.log(DataStore[0]);
      console.log("firstRecord.id#####",firstRecord.id);
      ServentID.value = firstRecord.id;
      ServentFName.value = firstRecord.SFName;
      ServentLName.value = firstRecord.SLName;
      ServentFFName.value = firstRecord.FFName;
      ServentFLName.value = firstRecord.FLName;
      console.log(ServentID.value);
    } else {
      console.log("Error in loading the data");
    }
  })
})
```

Also I am attaching my manifest.json file

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "This_Form_automation",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Autofill the form",
  "permissions": [
    "scripting",
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://www.police.rajasthan.gov.in/verificationform.aspx"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_idle",
      "js": [
        "content.js"
      ],
      "permissions": [
        "unsafe-inline"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "devtool": "source-map"
  },
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [
        "content.js"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "https://www.police.rajasthan.gov.in/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to fill the form by using a button which will work as trigger to get the data from json file and render that data into the web page form

Here I am attaching the error message which I am getting